# Clarifying UIList - Using parameters in list_template() and draw_item()?

Tags: python, scripting

I may have gotten some misinformation or have crossed wires from reading a number of different demos on UIList. I'm trying to clarify what I don't understand.

To place a UIList in a panel, according to [Blender API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_list), `template_list()` is called:

`template_list(listtype_name, list_id, dataptr, propname, active_dataptr, active_propname, item_dyntip_propname='', rows=5, maxrows=5, type='DEFAULT', columns=9, sort_reverse=False, sort_lock=False)`

This starts with 6 positional parameters (the only ones I'm dealing with at this point): listtype_name, list_id, dataptr, propname, active_dataptr, active_propname. I'm working [from a demo](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-uilists-in-blender/) that calls it with this line:

`row.template_list("MY_UL_List", "The_List", scene, "my_list", scene, "list_index")`

From what I understand, the last 4 items are:

- dataptr - the parent object of the list being used for data in the UIList class
- propname - the name of the list being used
- active_dataptr - the parent of the object being used as the index of the active item
- active_propname - the name of the index being used

What I don't understand is why the list object and the index aren't just passed as parameters instead of passing their parent object and their name, in string form. Along with that, when I'm writing my own draw_item() for my UIList class, how can I use this info? I'd especially like to get the propname or the actual list object being used by the UIList class or list_id. (I tried getting `self.propname` from inside draw_item() but it's not there. The same with `self.list_id`.)

My questions about `draw_item()` are similar. According to [Blender API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UIList.html#bpy.types.UIList.draw_item), this is a call to that routine:

`draw_item(context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_property, index=0, flt_flag=0)`

Again, I'm only dealing with the positional parameters, skipping `context` and `layout`, which leaves data, item, icon, active_data, and active_property. Why, in the parameter `data`, the parent object that contains our list (the CollectionProperty list) is passed, instead of the actual list object. Also, the name of the property used as an index is given in string form in `active_property`, but not the property or object itself.

It seems to me it'd be easier to just pass, in `draw_item()` the actual list and index objects than passing their parent and a name in string form. I'm assuming the answers to "Why isn't just the item passed?" are the same as they are for `list_template()`, but included this just in case they are different.

To summarize my questions:

1. Why are these parameters passed as the parent object of the list and list index (and then their names in string form) instead of the actual list and list index?
2. How do I access the list name passed to `list_template()` (or the list object)?

Comment: 2: `self.bl_idname`

Comment: @batFINGER That gives me the name of the UIList class, but what can I do to get the info in the `list_id` parameter passed to it in list_template()?

Comment: Absolutely no idea.  Had a play with the UI list simple template. Could find no issue with setting or not. OOps Misread thought it said first name.

Comment: @batFINGER Same here. Checked API docs, tried tests in a script and from the console. The way I found to detect what list it is in use is to either get the class name with `type(data).__name__`  to get the class name. The other is to read `active_property`, which is a string, and it has the name of the index object. Those are the only reliable ways I can find to detect which list your using. I'd like it more if there was something documented about that to state it clearly, but the closest is the definition of what to pass through `active_property`.

Comment: Small error in the above. Use `type(item).__name__` to get the class name of the ClassProperty that is being used for the list being displayed.